# iPhone: Remove single slash from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove single slash from the following string.

```
"{\"ID\":\"2\",\"OrderNo\":\"48\",\"Price\":\"95\",\"Title\":\"Sell out\"}"
```

I tried using the below code.

```
resultStr = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\'" withString:@""];
```

But it is not removing slash from the given string.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Log prints the same result with "{\"ID\":\"2\",\"OrderNo\":\"48\",\"Price\":\"95\",\"Title\":\"Sell out\"}" .. that's why i wanted to remove \ in it.

Comment: @Getsy: maybe you should post more code: how do you get this string, what are you doing with it and how did you do NSLog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you deserialize an escaped JSON string with NSJSONSerialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948427/how-can-you-deserialize-an-escaped-json-string-with-nsjsonserialization)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove slash(\) because its not store in the string. it just use for add double quotes(")

Comment: Not only they don't need to be removed - they can't be since they don't really exist.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo, an extra `'`

Try

```
resultStr = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Same issue even if i removed '.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there actually are slashes in that string?  It looks like they are just escaping the nested quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

As *@Piyush* said the `\` is not for itself it is an escape sequence for `" (double quotes)`. So instead of replacing `\ (slash)` you will need to replace `" (double quotes)` to get desired output.

```
resultStr = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```