# How can you deserialize an escaped JSON string with NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, nsjsonserialization

I have an iOS app that needs to process a response from a web service. The response is a serialized JSON string containing a serialized JSON object, looking something like this:

```
"{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }"
```

Note that this response is a JSON *string*, not a JSON object. What I need to do is deserialize the string, so that I get this:

```
{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21 }
```

And then I can use `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]` to deserialize that into an `NSDictionary`.

But, how do I do that first step?  That is, how to I "unescape" the string so that I have a serialized JSON object?  `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]` only works if the top-level object is an array or a dictionary; it doesn't work on strings.

I ended up writing [my own JSON string parser](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/5715018), which I hope conforms to [section 2.5 of RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5).  But I suspect I've overlooked some easy way to do this using `NSJSONSerialization` or some other available method.

Comment: Just cut off the leading and trailing quoteß and then replace all `\"`s with `"`.

Comment: Then you repeat the unescaping process for every possible escape sequence (there are finitely many).

Comment: The `\uXXXX` escape sequence makes simple search-and-replace difficult.

Comment: Well, it should not be difficult to write a simple scanner that goes through the string looking for escape characters and replacing them.

Comment: That's what I did: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/5715018

Comment: And is that not working?

Comment: It is working fine. But as I say in the question, I suspect there is a simpler way to use the existing API.

Comment: I don't know of anything in Cocoa which can backslash-escape and -unescape strings. There are methods for URL escaping, but that's different, as you surely know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31281/discussion-between-kristopher-johnson-and-h2co3)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have nested JSON, then just call `JSONObjectWithData` twice:

```
NSString *string =  @"\"{ \\\"name\\\" : \\\"Bob\\\", \\\"age\\\" : 21 }\"";
// --> the string
// "{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }"

NSError *error;
NSString *outerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
// --> the string
//  { "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21 }
NSDictionary *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[outerJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options:0 error:&error];
// --> the dictionary
// { age = 21; name = Bob; }
```

Comment: When I tried that, I got an error message. It seems to only work if the top-level object is an array or dictionary.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson: I tried exactly this code and it worked for me. You need the NSJSONReadingAllowFragments option in the first step.

Comment: I swear I tried `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` before, and it didn't work, but now it does.  Thanks for making me try it again.

Comment: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments is not for that. It just allows to parse a single JSON String, or JSON number, or other JSON primitive. The string has to be a "proper" JSON string, that is it is escaped. (properly encoded). However, the given string seems to be a complete proper JSON -- just encoded in some special way.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: I don't quite understand your comment. `"{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }"` *is* the properly JSON encoded form of the string `{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21 }` - and the latter happens to be the JSON  encoded form of a dictionary. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: IFF the given string is actually a proper string of a JSON, then you are right! I'm just not sure whether the given string is actually encoded this way, and why: If you put a key/value pair into a JSON representation - whose value os a JSON, you would retrieve exactly that JSON after it went over the wire. That is if you would print NSLog("JSON: %@", dict[@"json"]) - it would print: __{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21 }__

Comment: Just another attempt to clarify: if you want to send any string - and JSON _is_ a string - via a JSON parser/decoder - then you NEVER will encode that yourself. Instead, you create a "JSON representation" (a hierarchical object structure) and pass this the JSON Parser/Decoder. On the receiver side, you would run the parser, and get some other platform JSON representation - say a Foundation hierarchy. When retrieving the string, that was initialized on the receiver side with as a JSON, you get exactly that back - excluding character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to data:

```
NSString *string = @"{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: I do have an `NSData` object when I invoke `NSJSONSerialization`. So it is as if your code was `string = @"\"{ \\"name\\" : \\"Bob\\", \\"age\\" : 21 }\"";`

Comment: How are you getting that string?  It sounds like somewhere along the pipeline it's being double-escaped, and that's what you need to debug.

Comment: The web service is double-escaping it. You and I may agree that it shouldn't, but it does, and I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut off the leading and trailing quotes and then replace all \"s with ":

```
NSString *sub = [original substringWithRange:(NSRange){ 1, original.length - 2 }];
NSString *unescaped = [sub stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\" withString:@"\"];
```

Comment: That was my initial hacky workaround, but it only works if there are no other special characters in the string (`\n`, `\t`, `\u1234`, etc.).  But I can't assume that.

Comment: A JSON string would require to escape these characters. So, when a encoder is applied, it would just escape the escape: "(\\n)"

Answer (score -1):

One should first ask, why the server just don't include the JSON, as a sub structure.

But anyway. The string you got seems to be an *escaped* JSON. What that *actually* means, is totally up to the web service developer. I suspect, that just the double quotes and an escape itself have been escaped with an escape `\`. The resulting string is not "serialized" - JSON is already serialized - but *encoded*. In order to revert it back - you need to "unescape" or *decode* it again:

A little C++ snippet shows how (I know you asked for Objective-C -- but this is just too easy):

Edit: the code should also work for UTF-16 and UTF-32 -- with any endianness - and if the encoder just mechanically did what I suspect, it should also work for escaped unicode characters, e.g. \u1234 etc.

Edit - no, it won't work for UTF-16 and UTF-32. The sample would have to be fixed for that (which would be easy). But please ensure you have UTF-8 - which is almost always the case.

```
#include <iostream>

char input[] = u8R"___({ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 })___";

// Unescapes the character sequence "in-situ".
// Returns a pointer to "past-the-end" of the unescaped string.
static char* unescape(char* first, char* last) {
    char* dest = first;
    while (first != last) {
        if (*first == '\\') {
            ++first;
        }
        *dest++ = *first++;
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char* first = input;
    char* last = first + strlen(input);
    std::string s(input, unescape(first, last));

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

**{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21 }**

Comment: Your example operates on the in input `{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }`. But the actual server response was (as I understand it) `"{ \"name\" : \"Bob\", \"age\" : 21 }"` (note the leading and trailing quotation mark). That's why NSJSONReadingAllowFragments works.

Comment: OK, that means, NSJSONSerialization interprets this as a JSON string, and then returns this top level object - which is a NSString. So, effectively it applies a "JSON String decoder" to the given string. That might work - but I would anyway clarify how the given string has been decoded by the web service.