# NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData returns NSString

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData where I pass a NSData object. As a result I get a NSString instead of an NSDictionary. The complete line I have is:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDec = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

And the return is:

[image]

Why don't I get a NSDictionary back? My backend is PHP on the server...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the original JSON look like? Your server definitely hasn't accidentally encoded twice and returned a string object? `NSJSONSerialization` should normally return a dictionary or an array, and if you have `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` set as you do, it will also happily return one of the primitive types if that's all that it finds.

Comment: that is the string representation of the dictionary. you could do: NSLog(@"%@",jsonDec); and would see the dict as string in your console log.

Comment: reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. This is the error I get if I try to do the following: [[jsonDec objectForKey:@"result"] valueForKey:@"UserID"]

Comment: @CyberK: It seems to me that your server is sending "nested JSON" (for whatever reason). Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948427/how-can-you-deserialize-an-escaped-json-string-with-nsjsonserialization for a similar issue, perhaps you can use that.

Comment: The problem is on the server, which is sending twice-encoded JSON; try posting the PHP code you're using there.

Comment: Server side this is happening: json_encode(array('replyCode'=>'success','result'=>array('UserID' =>'xxx')));

Comment: You should return the result object.  Maybe set a response header to indicate Success.

Comment: I just echo the value in PHP... Strange thing is that everything looks OK. JSON looks valid etc, only I get a NSString back instead of a NSDictionary...

Comment: The issue seems to be on the server side of things.  Web requests as JSON should be dictionaries an/or arrays.

Comment: EIJay, ok but what is the issue then...

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you are using to echo that out?

Comment: echo json_encode(array('replyCode'=>'success','result'=>array('UserID' => mysql_insert_id())));

Comment: And what does that look like when you echo that out (raw data)?

Comment: {
    "replyCode": "success",
    "result": {
        "UserID": 36
    }
}

Comment: @CyberK Clearly, that's not the whole story on the PHP side, since your code in the comments below shows base64 decoding, etc. Somewhere else, you're re-encoding it as JSON again.

Comment: Yes I know, but what I do is: json_encode, then base64 that json, encode it with AES256, and then base64 that again. That is returned. On iOS I do the same process, but then decoding. And there I can see the result as a string in JSON, but if I then put that in the NSJSONSerializer I get the string back instead of the dictionary... If I put that again in an NSJSONSerializer, I get an array back. Problem is that the request sends multiple possibilities back. So one time that works, other time putting it 2 times in the serializer it fails...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDec;
NSError* error = nil;
jsonDec = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jData
                                          options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                            error: &error];

if (error)
{
     NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}
```

Apple doc: **NSJSONReadingMutableContainers** - Specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x10d25c950 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: your variable that you want to serialize

Comment: NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decMutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        
        NSData *jData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:decodedString];

Comment: you mess up encodings.

Comment: why is that? What do I mess up?

Comment: What does mutability have to do with his problem?

Comment: check this code: NSData* jData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)]

Comment: That's not possible, the return string is decrypted before I get to this point so I cannot simply call dataWithContentsOfURL. I use AFNetworking

Comment: Or check this code: NSData *jData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:decMutData];

Comment: if not help - check the coding on the server

Comment: The [NSData dataFromBase64String is an extension on NSData.

Comment: I do not understand for what you use this method... If you use AFNetworking: success block: (void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success. jData = JSON

Comment: because my return value is a AES256 encrypted string, it first gets decrypted into a base64 string etc... But we are going off topic here I think ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use this when consuming `JSON` responses (mine usually are arrays of dictionaries).  I prefer to use object type `id` and just use introspection to determine whether it is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.  BTW - my web requests are either done using AFNetworking (v2) or using the Azure SDK.

```
id jsonDec = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jData options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: What is your answer differs from mine?

Comment: Well you assign the serialized object into an `NSDictionary` which most of the time is a mistake.  Unless you know that all your responses will be a JSON dictionary, you should use id and then find out what you have.  Most of my requests end up as an `NSArray` of dictionaries.  You also use the option to create mutable objects which is not as efficient as using the immutable counterparts.

Comment: And BTW - I DID NOT down-vote your answer.  I really wish that when people down-vote an answer, the person also leaves a comment explaining why.

Comment: id is giving me the exact same result as if I wrote NSDictionary

Comment: While this is a reasonable practice, I don't think it has anything to do with the problem the OP is having.